# It will be deprecated SpreadsheetApp in Google Apps Script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, deprecated

I have the following doubt. Google recently announced that it will shut down the Sheets v3 API, and that it is necessary to use v4.

In google apps script I am using SpreadsheetApp, which I thought was independent of the api of sheet, since it does not require having it enabled in the project. Is SpreadsheetApp going to stop working also in March 2020?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said the SpreadsheetApp doesn't belong to the Sheets API, so it's not going to stop working.